# WPF data binding

Tags: c#, wpf

Работал когда-то с wpf, прошел курс, написал проект и забыл. И вот, опять имею с ним дело. Надо привязать параметр к тексту. Сам параметр - a.ProxyProvider.Count. Когда-то у меня была подобная проблема, и помню что там был какой-то подвох, но вот какой не помню, а код проекта найти так и не смог.

Код разметки с привязкой:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding a.ProxyProvider.Count, 
           UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">0</TextBlock>
```

Как-бы остальные привязки работают(команды кнопок там, код в том же файле).

Comment: Чем является `ProxyProvider`?

Comment: А что должен означать в теле элемента? Почему нельзя его просто оставить пустым?

Comment: Так вы определитесь, либо указывайте атрибут Text, либо тело элемента. Но одновременно

Comment: ProxyProvider - параметр. Объект класса, наследуется от List<Proxy>. Поле оставлять пустым не хотелось бы, там ведется подсчет элементов в списке и желательно чтобы этот нолик был.

Comment: Ну так добейтесь чтобы там куда вы привязываетесь был этот нолик. В любом случае вы не можете сразу указывать и значение в атрибуте и в теле элемента, это запрещено, WPF не даст это скомпилировать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Немного попробовал другие решения, посмотрел на примеры кода с привязкой которые у меня были. Проблема оказалась вот в чем: 
-во первых, 0. Убрал его, но работать так и не начало.
-во вторых, свойство имеет тип int. Насколько я понимаю, привязка к тексту работает нормально только со string.

Вроде реализовал INotifyPropertyChanged, все красиво, но с интом в упор работать не хочет. считывает 0, но значение не обновляется. Со стрингом же никаких проблем нету. Тут есть несколько вариантов: или сделать параметр стринговым, или использовать IValueConverter. Не могу утверждать что решение абсолютно правильное и никаких других вариантов нету, но в моем случае все работает.

Comment: Так вы работаете с TEXBLOCK.TEXT - он стринговый. int упаковывать в string.